# Find and Replace on import

Tags: excel, csv

I'm looking for a way to automatically do a find and replace after I have imported data from a CSV file. The date data in my CSV file has a time stamp that I do not want to use. Yes, I can do it manually but would like to automate it if possible.

The data in the left column is what I want to change to match what is in the right column.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asgvq.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Turn on the macro recorder, do your steps, stop it. Then, remove [`.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) and you should be able to run any time. May need to set a variable or two for the column. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you are using this data downstream with other formulas, you could just clean it then with `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1, 10))`

Comment: The macro recorder did the trick, I was just hoping to automate it after the import. Thanks!